# Mac browsers won't display my menu like windows

Tags: css, macos, wordpress, navigation, styles

I have this navigation menu here that looks like this on **windows browsers**:

[image]

But it displays differently in Mac Browsers

**Chrome** - as you can see Home is not displayed

[image]

**Firefox** - it is not aligned perfectly

[image]

I am using wordpress and here is the styling for the anchors

```
#header #access a{ -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); width:100%; z-index: 999; padding: 0 8px 0 14px; min-height:14px; display:block; position:relative; display:block; vertical-align:middle; }
#header .menu-header {min-height: 100%;}
#header .menu-header > ul{margin-top: 19px; font-size: 14px; max-height: 16px;}
#header .menu-header > ul > li{ float:left; text-align:left; display: block; border-left: 1px solid #ab917a;  max-height: 16px; z-index:1;}
#header .menu-header > ul > li:first-child{ border-left: none; }
#header .menu-header > ul > li > ul{padding-top: 20px;}
```

The menu is custom made and dynamically generated by wordpress, I copied this from the browser

```
    <div id="access" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-header">
           <ul id="menu-main" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-228" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-82 current_page_item menu-item-228"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-761" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-761"><a href="/about-chevy-chase-facial-plastic-surgery/">About Us</a>
    </li>
         <li id="menu-item-313" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-313"><a href="/washington-dc-plastic-surgery-photos/">Photo Gallery</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-287" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-287"><a href="/plastic-surgery-specials-chevy-chase/">Specials</a>

    </li>
       <li id="menu-item-238" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-238"><a href="/contact-facial-plastic-surgeon-chevy-chase/">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div> 
   </div> <!-- end access -->
```

I am currently using a jquery to insert span element to force it to display as a workaround.

I am using browserstack.com for testing and can't recreate the problem in jsfiddle T_T
I am hoping someone have already experience this and give me an input on how to fix it.

Please help Y_Y

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more of the code or create an example in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` from your style. I believe it overrides `z-index: 999`. Why this only renders the first button invisible, I do not know. But it is a webkit-specific feature, so it would explain why Firefox and IE works fine.